# ¿Cómo ordeno de menor a mayor una tabla 10*10 de números generados aleatorios en JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Tengo que hacer este ejercicio:
Mediante el generador de números aleatorios llenar una tabla de dos dimensiones (10,10) con números enteros comprendidos entre el 1 y el 99. La tabla deberá visualizarse en pantalla así como los números que se van generando, colocándolos en cada casilla de la tabla.
Ordenar la matriz anterior por filas y columnas, de menor a mayor, y visualizar la tabla ordenada a la derecha de la anterior.
No se ordenar la segunda tabla, como se haría.

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
    table,td{border:2px inset;
    border-color: rgb(0, 195, 255);
    border-collapse:collapse;
    text-align: center;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        num=[];
        contador=0;
        document.write("<table>");
        
        for(j=0;j<10;j++){
            contador=contador+1;
            document.write("<tr>");
            for(i=0;i<=10;i++){
                num=Math.round(Math.random()*99);
                document.write("<td>"+num+"</td>");
            }
            document.write("</tr>");
        }

        document.write("</table>");

        document.write("<br><br><br>")

        document.write("<table>");
        for(j=0;j<10;j++){
            contador=contador+1;
            document.write("<tr>");

            for(i=0;i<=10;i++){
                num=Math.round(Math.random()*99);
                document.write("<td>"+num+"</td>");
            }

            document.write("</tr>");

        }
        
        document.write("</table>");

        
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Respuesta gracias a: @Trauma y @Benito-B

El primer problema que veo es que usas num = [] y no haces un push de los números dentro del array, los vas sustituyendo con cada iteración, y así al final es imposible ordenarlos.

Hay que hacer dos bucles, uno para crear el array, y posteriormente, ordenarlo, y otro para hacer la tabla:

```
num = []; //Creamos el Array

for(i=0;i<100;i++){ //iteramos 100 veces
    nm=Math.round(Math.random()*99); //generamos en una variable nueva 'nm' un número aleatorio con cada iteración
    num.push(nm);   //Y le hacemos un push al mismo 'nm' en cada iteración también. Así tendremos 100 valores metidos dentro del Array
}

num.sort((a, b) => a -b); //Con esto ordenamos los valores del Array, es una forma simplificada del return

console.log(num); //Aqui podemos ver el array al completo ya ordenado


document.write("<table>"); //creamos la tabla
document.write("<tr>"); //Creamos la columna
for(i=0;i<num.length;i++){ //comenzamos a iterar con un cierre del length del array
    
    if(i%10 == 0){ //Si el valor de la iteración es divisible entre 10
        document.write("</tr>");    //cerramos columna, por tanto, se hará 10 veces, ya que hay 10 valores divisibles entre 10 con resto 0
                                    //Para hallar el resto, hay que usar x%y==0 
    }

    document.write("<td>"+num[i]+"</td>"); //en cada celda, imprimimos el valor del array iterado
}
document.write("</table>"); //cerramos tabla
```